# Not Able To Remove 'The Post Appeared First On' RSS

Tags: wordpress, rss, rss-reader

I imported some posts to my site from RSS but at the end of post this line appears - **This Post Appeared First On This site**. I removed rss code in yoast plugin. I tried this on another site where yoast plugin isn't installed, and same line appears at the end of content. All tutorials are with same solution of yoast plugin that didn't work for me. Any other method or soultion to remove that line? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please follow these steps

1. Click into your Yoast Settings from the sidebar of your WordPress admin.
2. Click **Advanced**
3. Click on the **RSS** tab
4. Remove the added text from the two boxes
5. Click **Save Changes**

Comment: sir i have already dont that but it's ok this line is not a big deal